# Getting difficulties installing epson L3215 printer on ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: command-line

shows E:dpkg was interrupted
i installed dpkg and lsb
updated and upgraded
downloaded epson printer utility 1.1.2-1 from "epson software center"
now while installing
shows unsupported file
If anyone can give me step by step command
please help me